# Is it secure to identify the current user in ActionCable using a signed cookie generated on sign-in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, authentication, cookies, actioncable

I'm creating an instant messaging app in Rails 5 to learn about ActionCable, and I'm trying to understand how to make sure users connect to and stream from a channel securely.

When users subscribe, they stream from a channel specified by their user ID. This user ID is obtained from a signed cookie generated when the user signs in to the app. (That signed cookie is assigned by the `connect` method in `ActionCable::Connection` to a `current_user` variable, which is in turn used by the `subscribed` method in the `ChatChannel` to specify the channel the user streams from.)

My question broadly is whether this is secure.

Specifically:

- is it OK to assume that the signed cookie used to define `current_user` (and so to determine which channel the user streams from) is definitely the signed cookie generated when the user signs in? Or would it be possible to sign in, then connect to the ActionCable Connection using a cookie generated outside of the app? If this 'connection' were a regular HTTP request, a signed cookie containing a user ID wouldn't be enough to prove it was that user making the request;
- would it be possible for someone to change the `current_user` variable *after* the ActionCable Connection has been made - to a different user's ID - so they could then subscribe to a different channel?
- users need to be signed in to access the app's index action (which renders the messaging interface), but could they connect to the ActionCable Connection without accessing the index action, so without signing in, and with a different signed cookie generated outside the app containing a user ID? (`App.cable.subscriptions.create "ChatChannel"` is called when the index page renders, but what is the protection against that being called by someone who isn't signed in?)

I'm using Devise to sign users in, and am just adding to the default session method to generate the signed cookie used to set the ActionCable::Connect `current_user`:

```
def create
  super do |user|
    cookies.signed[:user_id] = user.id if user_signed_in?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I came across this in the ActionCable docs and using the user id alone to authenticate anything set off a few alarm bells!

Personally I'd go with storing the user ID in a signed cookie along with a token which expires after a certain amount of time and on log-out. But the most important thing to add from me would to ensure SSL is installed for the entire site.

The most basic type of session hijacking, that is, someone on a public unsecured network using a packet sniffer to get the session key should be mitigated by a correctly installed SSL certificate across the entire site.

If the attacker has access to the machine and can get the session cookie as well as any other cookie, in my opinion, we've already lost, as you said setting an expiry on the login is probably the best way of limiting damage.

You could also:

- Checking the IP of each request to make sure it's coming from the same place (still vulnerable to spoofing).
- Checking the user-agent of the browser to make sure it's the same machine and browser type (again, spoofing).
- Limit the user to one session at a time.

But these options aren't very effective and can impact the user experience. Put it this way, if a user hasn't put in place basic client side security; like password protection on their OS or they have let a malicious person on to their machine, then unfortunately the responsibility for the breach is on their shoulders, not yours.

I was interested in how the most popular session based sites dealt with this and wanted to see how easy it was to session hijack myself, so had a look at what Facebook we're doing and found this quite interesting method of protecting users;

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think I now have an answer.

I was able to stream another user's messages by doing the following:

- sign in as user A
- copy the string in the user_id signed cookie
- log in as user B
- delete the new signed cookie
- in the JS console create a new cookie called user_id with the string copied from user A's cookie as the content
- refresh the browser to reload the page's javascript and reconnect to the ActionCable::Connection instance

So the signed cookie is as insecure as it possible for a user to steal another user's signed cookie (or its contents).

But actually that doesn't make it less secure than a regular HTTP request authorised by the presence of a user ID in the server's session, where the user has to have a cookie with an encrypted session ID matching the server's session ID. Essentially the session cookie is in that authorising the user, and it's only as secure as the assumption that the user given the cookie is the user making the new request through their browser.

So the question is how possible is it to steal a cookie, or its contents. That can be made harder by:

- changing the cookie each time a user logs in (so a single theft/forgery only gives temporary access)
- using encrypted cookies so the content cannot be easily guessed
- not storing the content of the cookie in a database - storing a hashed version instead (which means not just using user IDs, for example, but instead storing a hashed token for each user, though a token would need to be used in combination with a user ID to guarantee a unique reference to each user
- assigning a user ID and a token to a cookie and requiring the correct combination of the two parts to be provided - for the same reason guessing a password that exists in the whole database is easier than guessing an individual's password